# concept of intrinsic derivative in light of covariant derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

> What is the basic difference between ordinary differentiation ,
> covariant differentiation and intrinsic differentiation ?

While taking a first course in tensor analysis , I was taught that ordinary derivative of a tensor may not produce a tensor necessarily . So we need to define a covariant derivative in order to fulfill that gap . But I am confused why we need to define an intrinsic one particularly . It is defined that for some mixed tensor $A^i_j$ having components as functions of a parameter $t$ we have the intrinsic derivative $$\frac{\delta A^i_j}{\delta t}=A^i_{j, \ k}\frac{dx^k}{dt}=\left(\frac{\partial A^i_j}{\partial x^k}+\Gamma^i_{lk}A^l_j-\Gamma^l_{jk}A^i_l\right)\frac{dx^k}{dt}$$ $$\implies\frac{\delta A^i_j}{\delta t}=\frac{dA^i_j}{dt}+(\Gamma^i_{lk}A^l_j-\Gamma^l_{jk}A^i_l)\frac{dx^k}{dt}$$ where $x^k(t)$ are coordinates in the manifold .

So what does it make the difference between a covariant derivative and intrinsic derivative despite the fact that both produce a tensor ? In fact , why do we even need to define it as presented above ? Any help is appreciated .

Comment: Be aware that mathematicians use the term *intrinsic derivative* in a totally different sense. If one has a section of a vector bundle, at a *zero* of the section one can compute what is called the intrinsic derivative of the section. I cannot imagine why the formula you've written down is "intrinsic" at all.

Comment: But in this link "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_KPM2lL1xE" they defined the same formula (for rank $1$ tensors) and labelled as intrinsic derivatives , that's why I am confused .

Comment: As I knew would be the case, this is a relativist, not a mathematician. They use notations and language that are quite different from mathematicians. The "intrinsic derivative" is a misnomer; it is merely the covariant derivative calculated along a curve.